# Equation related to the radioactive decay being random

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, radiation, radioactivity

How is **time** decay randomness calculated? it's similar that on variables like **position**?

If we describe a system with $\phi\left(x,t\right)$ as wave function, $\left|\phi\left(x,t\right)\right|^2$ as probability. From probability density we can calculate probability of a given **position**. We can answer questions like "what's the probability of measuring a particle in $x_0$ (spatial coordinate)?". So uncertainty is about **$x$**.

In a radioactive decay, uncertainty is in **time** of occurrence, it's not about position, that's this question about, what are the equation related to this probability computation? Is there a "time operator"?

It's easy to confuse randomness in position with time, because given any fixed $x_0$ (or a neighborhood zone), we will have to wait random time to get a hit there, of course, but that's not this question about!, that's ***spatial*** distribution of probability, the "when" of a radioactive decay event doesn't depend on "where" it hits.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/151222/simple-real-life-examples-of-fermis-golden-rule).

Comment: If you want a wavefunction description of radioactive decay, then look at Gamow's model for alpha decay: https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/3779576931836/Ex8Serie1/ Also, in every non-ridiculous situation, a nucleus is at least somewhat localized, so there is both a spatial and a time dimension to the probability of measuring a decay.

Comment: @probably_someone Do you know such an article that is accessible for the public? Your link requires credentials.

Answer (score 1):

The [exponential decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) formalism typically describes persistence of populations, so it is a probability distribution of cumulative outcome, so persistence probability, not transition instant. In a naive 2-state system, it could amount, schematically, to something of the sort,
$$
|\langle \psi| e^{-iHt/\hbar}|\psi\rangle|^2 \sim e^{-t/\tau}/\tau.
$$

Of course, in realistic situations, there are more final states involved, and more elaborate formulas computable via [Fermi's golden rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule), itself a consequence of [time-dependent perturbation theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_(quantum_mechanics)#Time-dependent_perturbation_theory), but it is not clear to me these methods are what you are asking about, specifically.

For one particle, the same distribution  specifies the distribution of decay times, with *τ* as the mean time of the particle's demise, the lifetime.

If the rate is small (rare events), it is a random, (homogeneous) [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process); are you asking about the QM determination of the salient parameters (like the rate 1/*τ*)? It underlies the above [exponential decay law](http://secular.me.uk/physics/radioactivity-summary.pdf). Typically, you may  find the distribution of times between decays (Fig. 3) in the entire population.

- In QM, time is a parameter, not a dynamical variable, and as such there is no "operator" for it. The Hamiltonian operator effects time translations.

Answer (score -2):

"Time decay randomness" is calculated by calculating the transition probability. Radioactive decay, like any quantum transition, is a stochastic process. We can calculate with what probability it occurs, but we we do not know when this probability will materialise.

This stochastic behaviour is the essence of quantum mechanics.